# Link Access table to Excel with Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, ms-access, hyperlink, ms-office, linked-tables

I am trying to create a linked table in Access to my Excel spreadsheet that includes hyperlinks. After going through the wizard, my table does not have hyperlinks anywhere. The field type is automatically set to Short Text.

Does anyone know of a fix or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think your terminology is a little messed up, but I'm guessing you are referring to this concept, right.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command0_Click()

     'Macro Loops through the specified directory (strPath)
     'and links ALL Excel files as linked tables in the Access
     'Database.

    Const strPath As String = "C:\your_path_here\" 'Directory Path
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

     'Loop through the folder & build file list
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    While strFile <> ""
         'add files to the list
        intFile = intFile + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
        strFileList(intFile) = strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
     'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'cycle through the list of files & link to Access
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
        DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , _
        strFileList(intFile), strPath & strFileList(intFile), True, ""
         'Check out the TransferSpreadsheet options in the Access
         'Visual Basic Help file for a full description & list of
         'optional settings
    Next
    MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " Files were Linked"

End Sub
```

It is probably better to practice with CSV files, which are easier to work with, compared to Excel files.  To loop through Excel files in a folder, and link to each, just change one line of code.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , "Your table name","Path to your workbook file", True, "Sheet1!Ran
```